# Member Relationships to single Entry

Tags: channel-entries, members, relationships, ee3, related-entries

I have a tournaments channel where ppl will be able to add tourney's through front end. I now need other members to be able to submit a "team" to a specific tourney entry.  There will need to be like 10 "teams" linking to a specific "tournament" channel.  I'm trying to figure out best scenario for Teams to register for tourney's.

I was also thinking of allowing someone entering a team to select/seach from a list of "members".  I don't think you can have a relationship to members though.  Any advice for all this?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you might want to consider is using the [VMG Chosen Member](https://github.com/vector/VMG-Chosen-Member) add-on.

Chosen Member gives you the ability to assign members to channel entries without having to turn those member details into entries in a parallel channel, and also provides some tools for hooking out member data fields into templates (so if a member is associated with a channel entry, you can pull information into a template displaying that channel entry from their member profile).  It is very handy, and a lot simpler to work with than Zoo Visitor (for example), and (since it does not replicate member data into a channel) is very "DRY".

Also, Chosen Member is compatible with EE3, Zoo Visitor is (AFAIK) EE2 only.

HTH

Comment: I think it's definitely what I need and was planning on implementing a type ahead plugin like this.  I made a Teams channel with all these field types for players just to try it.  However this doesn't really solve my "teams" assigned to tournaments issue.  I'm thinking a teams channel is still best option with relationship to a tournament entry.  At least with VMG Chosen Member though I can let captains search entire member list.  thank you!

Comment: Yep, curiously been working on what sounds like a broadly similar concept - I have gone making 'teams' a channel, and each team is an entry in that channel, with a leader, helpers and members pulled into separate VMG Chosen Member fields.  Separately I've got something similar to 'competitions' which link via relationships to teams (and also to things like a channel with info on the entities organising the competitions).  Seems to work OK, and is quite flexible.  So I think you are on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd party member module (zoo visitor etc) which stores member data in channel entries.

With data in channels you are then free to use relationships.

I did this a while ago and went well down the rabbit hole but your scenario sounds reasonable but with multiple groups and 'captains" you will need some obfuscation to stop 'captains' from editing other teams.

Comment: unfortunately that add-on doesn't say it's compatible with ee3 yet.  It does sound like what I want though, have members be inside channels.  I am going to have to manually create members from another site that accepts payments, so there's always that possibility I just create them as channels anyways and have a custom login so it's not using native ee login.  hmmm